# Enable SonarLint in Visual Studio automatically

Tags: visual-studio, sonarlint

How can I enable SonarLint in Visual Studio automatically? 
Every time I open Visual Studio I must to enable it manually, because it is always disabled

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Try uninstalling and then installing again Sonar Lint for Visual Studio.

A possible reason for this behavior is if Sonar Lint was installed twice in your Visual Studio. I don't know how this could happen, but there is a tool that can detect this situation: [DuplicateExtensionFinder](https://github.com/remcoros/DuplicateExtensionFinder). Here is a GitHub comment that talks about this behavior [Source](https://github.com/madskristensen/BundlerMinifier/issues/214#issuecomment-271271079)

Comment: I reinstalled Sonar Lint and ran beautifully.

Comment: What does DuplicateExtensionFinder have to do with this?

Comment: @Enrico, the DuplicateExtensionFinder is used to check if for some reason Sonar Lint got installed twice on your machine. This should not happen normally, but is a possible reason for disabling the extension on VS load. For details you can read the GitHub issue in the "Source" link in my answer.